# Cannot save dbRecord using AngularJS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am ashamed that I ask so strange question. However, if someone knows what the error is, I'll be really glad!

I've just start learning AngularJS in ASP.NET MVC. To do this I downloaded sample from Microsoft website - [CRUD Operations in MVC 5 using WebAPI with AngularJS](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CRUD-Operations-in-MVC-5-d4ff2263#content). I've tried ask where [the project is uploaded](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CRUD-Operations-in-MVC-5-d4ff2263/view/Discussions#content), but questons will be answered in two-three weeks.

I hope that a lot of people have met this example and solved this problem.

When I click "Save" after editing some person, then I just see infinite image. I waited twenty minutes, but "Friend" is not updated. How can I resolve it? I would like to edit and save Friends.

How can I save the item?

In my view this method should be called:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Friend friend)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
   }
   if (id != friend.FriendId)
   {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
   }

   db.Entry(friend).State = EntityState.Modified;
   try
   {
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
   {
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
   }
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

What I see is just infinite loading:
[image]

However, nothing updates. Just always image is shown. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between client side (angular) and server-side (.NET).  I can see you're using chrome, fire up the Developer Console and look at the http request.

Did it reach the server? If not; check the request on client side. Otherwise; breakpoint on the server and check the posted object and signature of Friend. There is probably a mismatch on property names etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted `id` parameter from the signature of:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(Friend friend)
```

and this worked for me.
The whole code snippet:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(Friend friend)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
   }

   db.Entry(friend).State = EntityState.Modified;
   try
   {
      db.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
   {
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
   }
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Maybe it helps somebody:).